# Why does $P(A,B | C) = P(A|C) \cdot P(B|C)$

Tags: probability, chain-rule, naive-bayes

I'm in an NLP course learning about naive bayes statistics. We briefly went over joint and conditional probabilities.

Why does $P(A,B | C) = P(A|C)\cdot P(B|C)$

Comment: No, it is not the "chain rule". This property is usually called conditional independence - $A, B$ are conditional independence given $C$.

Comment: Assuming that $,$ means intersection, this is not true in general. Even if $A,B$ are independent.

Comment: When would it be true and when would it not @copper.hat?

Comment: See @BGM's comment.

Comment: As BGM said, $\mathsf P(A,B\mid C)=\mathsf P(A\mid C)~\mathsf P(B\mid C)$ *means* that $A$ and $B$ are *conditionally independent* when given $C$.

Comment: See @GrahamKemp's answer.

Comment: See @copper.hat's answer.

Comment: I think this is just a simplifying assumption that is made when deriving the naive Bayes classifier. Perhaps this is why it's called "naive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not true in general. For example, take the three following events from rolling a six-sided die:

- A = "Is odd"
- B = "Is prime"
- C = "Is at least 3"

Then $P(A|C) = 1/2$ and $P(B|C) = 1/2$, but $P(A,B|C) = 1/2$ as well.

The equation $P(A|C) P(B|C) = P(A,B|C)$ is the definition of what it means for $A$ and $B$ to be independent events when conditioned on $C$.